# Doesn't work EditText padding in the API 21

Tags: android, padding

Doesn't work EditText padding in the API 21. I try to do it in empty project, only with single editText, but it still doesn't work.

Set padding programmatically works, but in my work project, I've a lot of EditTexts with different paddings and  set padding programmatically isn't right way.

On API level 19 xml padding works well.

Are there any solutions?

This my EditText xml code:

```
   <EditText
   android:id="@+id/et_text"
   android:text="Text"
   android:paddingLeft="20dp"
   android:paddingStart="20dp"
   android:paddingRight="20dp"
   android:paddingEnd="20dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="45dp"/>
```

In the result, I've got:[image]

I expect:

[image]

Comment: Same issue here. My edittexts won't apply the padding after I updated to API 21.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is android bug. In future it will be fix.

[Bug report on google code.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=label%3APriority-Small&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=77982#makechanges)

Comment: bug was closed on 18 december, hopefully it will be released in next release of... Of what?

Comment: This doesn't look like it will be fixed because using `android:paddingStart` is the work around

Answer (score 4):

Solved it by creating a custom edittext with padding and use it in xml.

```
public class MyEditTextView extends EditText{

public MyEditTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyEditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyEditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    int paddingLeftRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.edittext_padding);
    int topPadding = this.getPaddingTop();
    int bottomPadding = this.getPaddingBottom();
    setPadding(paddingLeftRight, topPadding, paddingLeftRight, bottomPadding);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `android:paddingLeft` with `android:paddingStart`, as should be anyway and fixes this bug on those devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give padding programmatically by using method setLayoutParams() it will work i am hopeful 
Ref: [Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-set-padding-programmatically-in.html)

Comment: In my project, I'm using a lot of edittexts with different paddings and set padding programmatically - isn't rigth way to solve this task.

Comment: Confirming that setting the padding programmatically works, but I agree with @user3134124 that it's hugely annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the best way to work around the problem, but it works for me: you can set **android:layout_height** attribute to some fixed value and set **android:gravity** to *center* or *center_vertical*

```
<EditText
        ...
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        .../>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it in styles, using android standart edittext:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
</style>
```