# Android Studio | paddingLeft and paddingStart not showing on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, padding

For some reason the android:paddingLeft and/or android:paddingStart I am using in my layout file is not working when I run it on my device (HTC One M8). I have tried a combination of android:paddingLeft with android:paddingStart, as well as both by themselves.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_Username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/textlines"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/s_red" />
```

Here are some links to screenshots that I have taken. (Sorry first post, I do not have the reputation to upload images).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMpmJ.jpg

I have tried using a different device (Samsung Galaxy S4) as well as building it from different systems but I keep getting the same issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit:

As per Kirill's suggestion, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685658/add-padding-on-view-programmatically) and came up with this in the Activity onCreate function:

```
EditText pw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
EditText un = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Username);
pw.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
un.setPadding(20,0,20,0);
```

And it works great, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:padding
```

If you use API 21 - it is a bug.

[Look this, may be it can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489832/doesnt-work-edittext-padding-in-the-api-21)

Comment: @Kenstar you can try set the padding programmatically, may be it solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:paddingStart` instead, it replaces this anyway and fixes this bug.